# Correct Querying for Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

So I am trying to build a forum in laravel,

So far I have all the user stuff done. Now I am just trying to think of a decent database structure for the forum..

I was thinking of going like so

Categories which inside have Sub Categories and inside sub categories you have Posts and inside the post you have comments, so I was going to go like so

forum_categories

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('forum_category')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('slug')->unique();
$table->string('category_name');
$table->string('category_description');
$table->datetime('locked')->nullable();
$table->datetime('deleted')->nullable();
$table->integer('disabled_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
```

Now I was going to use categories for the main categories but also the sub categories, Now there is no issue with this however I am using the category name as slugs as i dislike IDS in URLS but this causes an issue when im pulling info for the sub categories

I have to Query the database for which category holds the slug $slug and then select the id and then do another query for which rows have the ids

```
$cat = ForumCategory::whereSlug($slug)->select('id')->firstOrFail();
$category = ForumCategory::whereNull('deleted')->whereParentId($catId)->get();
```

Is this a bad way of doing things? If i was just using the IDS it would be 1 query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

I think you have to use eloquent relationships. Go through the documentation.

Comment: yeah i Know what relationships are but if you are using the same table for subcategories as you are for categories this is mute isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Arigna was correct I set up a relationship using the same table, then just did the same query However! my soft delete method was ignored as when doing this you can not add any extra query modifications.

So I also had to set up soft deletes on the model

I ended up with this

```
public function subcategory($slug)
{
    $category = ForumCategory::whereSlug($slug)->first();
    $category->ForumSubCategory();
    return view('forum.index', [
        'category' => $category->ForumSubCategory,
        ]);
}
```